# Spoiler and List problem

Tags: bug, markdown, formatting, spoilers

Is is possible to make a spoiler space with a numbererd list inside?

> ! Here is what I have tried:
>
> ! 1. The first.
>   ! 2. The second.

or

> Here is what I have tried:
>
>  1. The first.
>  2. The second.

or

> ! Here is what I have tried:
>   1. The first.
>   2. The second.

or

> Here is what I have tried:
>  1. The first.
>  2. The second.

But nothing works... I guess it is a bug.

Edit. The solution provided in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129445/358093) mentioned by quid works fine for pure text like above:

> Here is the proposed workaround:
>
> ```
>  1. The first.
>  2. The second.
> ```

but has a problem with formulae:

> Here is the proposed workaround:
>
> ```
>  1. The first $n$.
>  2. The second $k$.
> ```

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129441/markdown-not-appropriately-rendering-unordered-list-spoilers If it's a bug, it's likely a  won't fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a double space at the end of each line to force a newline:

```
>! Here is the proposed workaround:  
>!  
>! 1. The first $n$.  
>! 2. The second $k$.
```

This will preserve the formulas as well:

> Here is the proposed workaround:
>
>  1. The first $n$.
>  2. The second $k$.

Comment: This doesn't make list as list, but it wasn't an end in itself.